# Function space and contractibility

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\map{map}$I have the following question:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Let $\map(X,Y)$ denote the space of non-constant continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$. Suppose moreover that each continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ is homotopic to a fixed continuous function $f \colon X \to Y$. In case $f$ is a homeomorphism, is it true that $\map(X,Y)$ is contractible?

I am grateful if anyone has any counterexamples or what conditions must be imposed on $X$ and $Y$ for the question to be true?

Comment: Sorry, the way you've formulated looks funny: every continuous map should be homotopically equivalent to a continuous map? Sounds like an empty condition to me...

Comment: @Echo : I think $f$ is supposed to be fixed :)

Comment: It might be misleading to remove constant functions from $\mathrm{map}(X,Y)$. Moreover if $Y$ is not totally path-disconnected, and if $X$ is not too small, constant functions are homotopic to non-constant functions, so the artefact of removing constant functions will not be helpful.

Comment: There's a subject called "obstruction theory" that gives you an answer to this question.  Perhaps look at Whitehead's book on homotopy theory?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a negative answer to one precise formulation of your question. Let $F(X,Y)$ denote the space of maps that are not homotopic to a constant map. Then $F(X,Y)$ can be path connected and contain a homeomorphism without $X$ being contractible.

For example, take $X = B \mathbb Z/2$.  Then every map $X \to X$ is either homotopy equivalent to a constant map or to the identity map.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists a homotopy equivalence $f: X\to Y$ and every other $h$ is homotopic to $f$, then $f$ is homotopic to a constant map, so that $X,Y$ are contractible, and therefore so is $map(X,Y)$.

Except if $Y$ is empty, but then so is $X$, and therefore $map(X,Y)$ is still contractible (for a different reason, though)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and you are right. It was my mistake not to eliminate constant functions. I forgot to formulate my hypotheses correctly since I am trying to prove something in higher category theory. (In that context, constant functors are not allowed due to the nature of the functors I am working with). But having a topological idea will help me.